# JCS: How to access cache in two different applications running in same server

Tags: jcs

jcs: I have two applications running in Glassfish.  How do I retrieve cache stored in one application to another application

Comment: Have you tried anything before?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shared auxiliary region cache (disk, jdbc, lateral) with the same coordinates (configs).

Cache elements from application A will be available on application B when you check it or get it from shared cache.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/JCSPlugins.html